# multiplication table using two nested loops but i am getting an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nested-loops

I am trying to create a table like...

desired:

[image]

but my code is coming out like..

actual:

[image]

my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + "\t");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                if (i > 0) Console.Write(i * j + "\t");
                else Console.Write(j + "\t");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

how do I add the `*` and the `-, |`?

Comment: just ad a bunch of if statements in the outer for loop. eg. if i=0 print "*" else print i. and then print \t | \t. And in the end after the print \n ad an if i=0 then print a bunch of "-" chars then new line again. everything else you've done

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many different ways, some could be much better, based on your code it can be like this:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/hZZcqJ

```
using System;
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209099/multiplication-table-using-two-nested-loops-but-i-am-getting-an-error

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("*\t|\t");
            }
            else
            {

                Console.Write(i + "\t|\t");
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                    if(j*i>9)
                        Console.Write(i * j + "\t");
                    else
                        Console.Write(i * j + " \t");
                else
                    Console.Write(j + "\t ");
            }

            Console.Write("\n");
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++)
                {
                    if(k>2)
                        Console.Write(" -\t");
                    else
                        Console.Write("-\t");
                }

                Console.Write("\n");
            }

            Console.Write("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("*\t | \t");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(i + "\t | \t");
            }


            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(i * j + "\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(j + "\t");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");

            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Comment: *        |      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
-------------------------1       |      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
2        |      2       4       6       8       10      12      14      16      18

Comment: it is showing the " --" on the second line pushing back the second like of numbers

Answer (score 0):

TRy this :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            PrintRow(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintRow(int i)
    {
        var args = new List<string>();
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
            {
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    args.Add("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (k == 1)
                    {
                        args.Add("|");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        args.Add((k - 1).ToString());
                    }
                }
            }   

        }
        else
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
                {
                    args.Add("-----");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
                {
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        args.Add((i - 1).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (k == 1)
                        {
                            args.Add("|");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            args.Add(((i - 1) * (k -1)).ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,5}{1,5}{2,5}{3,5}{4,5}{5,5}{6,5}{7,5}{8,5}{9,5}{10,5}", args.ToArray()));
    }
```

Comment: The program doesn't stay open for me to check the coding. Once I hit start the screen pops up then its gone.

Comment: If you want to pause the console window to see the result, add Console.ReadLine(); right after the for loop in main method. See update

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    if i == 0
    {
        Console.Write("* \t");
    }
    else if i != 1
    {
        Console.Write(i > 1 ? i - 1 : i + "\t");
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        if i == 1
        {
            Console.Write(i + "\t - \t");
        }
        else
        {
            if j == 1
            {
                Console.Write(i + "\t | \t");
            }        

            if i > 0
            {
                Console.Write((i > 1 ? i - 1 : i) * j + "\t");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(j + "\t");
            }
        }
        j = j + 1
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well.. why go through all that code, when you can do it rly simple

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
            {
                int resultat = i * j;
                Console.Write(resultat.ToString().PadLeft(4));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace PracticingCSharp
{
    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
                {
                    Console.Write( x*y +"\t");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer solves the asked problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

// 2D grid times table

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
 {
      for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++)
      {
           int result = i * j;

           Console.Write("{0,4}", result);
      }
                Console.WriteLine();
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```